# Why is this a subspace of a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

This seems like a very trivial problem but I am having trouble wrapping my mind around the reasoning behind the answer.

The problem is:

> Let $V$ be the (real) vector space of all functions $f$ from $\mathbb R$ into $\mathbb R$. Which of the following sets of functions are subspaces of $V$?
>
> - all $f$ such that $f(3) = 1 + f(-5)$

And the solution I found was:

> Not a subspace. Let $f(x)$ be the function defined by $f(3) = 1$ and $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \ne 3$. Let $g(x)$ be the function defined by $g(-5) = 0$ and $g(x) = 1$ for all $x \ne -5$. Then both $f$ and $g$ satisfy the condition. But $$(f + g)(3) = f(3) + g(3) = 1 + 1 = 2,$$ while $$1 + (f + g)(-5) = 1 + f(-5) + g(-5) = 1 + 0 + 0 = 1.$$ Since $1 \ne 2$, $f + g$ does not satisfy the condition.

The initial condition is very specific as to the input, you have $f(3) = 1 + f(-5)$, how can he assume that $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \ne 3$ or that $g(x) = 1$ for all $x \ne -5$? Wouldn't that be outside of the set and thus invalid for a proof?

Isn't this problem the equivalent of asking, is $g = g$ a subspace of $V$?

Comment: The most fundamental axiom of vector spaces says that there must exists a zero vector. In the case of functions the zero vector must be the zero function $f(x)=0$ for all $x$. In the solution they explain why this function is not a part of the set and therefore the set can not be a subspace.

Comment: If you want to show that the set $S=\{ f \in V : f(3)=1+f(-5) \}$ is not a vector space, it is sufficient to show that the set does not satisfy some of the properties that characterize vector spaces. Since vector spaces are closed under sums, it is sufficient to show that there are two functions $f$, $g \in S$ such that $f+g\not\in S$. The solution you mention accomplishes this by defining the two very particular functions and proving that they belong to $S$, but their sum is outside of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define $f(3)=1$ and $f(x)=0$ for any other $x$. Hence $f(-5)=0$. And then $1=f(3)=1+0=1+f(-5)$, so it's fine.

Anyway, there is a much easier proof this set is not a subspace. If it was a subspace then the zero function would be there. But it isn't there, because if $f$ is the zero function then $f(3)=0$ but $1+f(-5)=1+0=1$.

Comment: Yes, the zero proof is logical. The problem I have is, is it valid to state that f(x) = (some value) for any other x? Since you are given a specific value to work with, is it valid to assume that which wasn't stated for your proof?

Comment: Yes, of course. Your space $V$ contains all functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. So you can take any real valued functions you wish. In the proof you showed they took two specific functions that satisfy the property $f(3)=1+f(-5)$ but their sum doesn't.

Comment: Aha, okay that answered it, thank you for your time!

Comment: You're welcome.